# difference between Creating a Kafka Sink for Streaming Queries and Writing the output of Batch Queries to Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

in this [spark to kafka webpage](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html), it gives two scenarios for writing data from spark to Kafka, one is `Creating a Kafka Sink for Streaming Queries` and the other is `Writing the output of Batch Queries to Kafka`. I'm wondering what's the difference between them.

In my case, we already have a daily spark batch job which generate bunch of data, and we're seeking a connector solution which can ingest these data to Kafka. Which case of these two scenarios from that webpage is suited for our case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "have a daily spark **batch** job which generate bunch of data"

I guess you are providing the answer yourself. If you have a batch dataframe which runs once (compared to a streaming job which runs continuously) tha batch Kafka sink is what you are looking for.

You could also indicate this by looking how your DataFrame is created, through `read` (batch) or through `readStrem` (streaming).

If you are still unsure which one to pick, you will be notified at runtime as it will not be possible to mix batch and streaming processinh in the same query. So trial and error will also get you to a solution.